# Re-run a code from a particular point

Tags: python

I don't know how to re-run a certain piece of my code:

```
print('Welcome to your currency converter\n Please choose your starting currency from the four options:')
currency1=input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()
if currency1!='gdp' or 'eur' or 'usd' or 'jpy':
    print('Sorry not accepted try again')
```

When the code prints `Sorry not accepted try again` I want to start the code again. How do I do this?

Comment: You may want to check out [this tutorial](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science-subject/computer-science/v/while-loops-in-python)... :)

Comment: `'gdp'or'eur'or'usd'or'jpy'` evaluates to `'gdp'`  You probably want `currency not in ['gdp', 'eur', 'usd', 'jpy']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this than the other answers reccomend, is to put the condition in the while statement like this:

```
print('Welcome to your currency converter\n Please choose your starting currency from the four options:')
currency1 = input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()

while currency1 not in ['gdp', 'eur', 'usd', 'jpy']:
    print('Sorry not accepted try again')
    currency1 = input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()
```

Comment: DRY violation -- you've got the currency question in two places.

Comment: @DSM Well, that's the problem with not having `do ... while` to work with. I think it looks better than having a `if ... else` statement inside the while loop, but I guess that's subjective.

Comment: The official [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression) says that this option "… seems attractive but is generally less robust", and goes on to explain why (but basically, DSM summarized it perfectly in two words).

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a `while` loop, to keep running the code "while" it's invalid:

```
while True:
    currency1 = input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()
    if currency1 not in ('gdp', 'eur', 'usd', 'jpy'):
        print('Sorry not accepted try again')
    else:
        break
```

**Note:** `currency1!='gdp'or'eur'or'usd'or'jpy'` doesn't do what you think it does. Use the `in` method as above

Edited per abarnert's comment

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `else: break` and get rid of the flag, as in Markku K.'s deleted answer.

Comment: @abarnert, gawd, how many times have I done this without thinking of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The official FAQ covers three options for this, although you'd probably never find it because it's under the question [Why can't I use an assignment in an expression](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression):

---

First, there's `while True:`

```
print('Welcome to your currency converter\n Please choose your starting currency from the four options:')
while True:
    currency1=input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()
    if currency1 not in ['gdp','eur','usd','jpy']:
        print('Sorry not accepted try again')
    else:
        break
```

This may seem odd to diehard C programmers, who were taught that `break` (like early `return` and similar features) is bad. But Python isn't C. (Not to mention that nowadays, even MISRA recommends using `break` in new C99 code…) You can avoid the `break` by using `while not done:` and setting `done = True` instead of `break`, but there is no advantage to that, and it just makes your code longer and more complicated.

---

Next, there's `while <condition>:`

```
print('Welcome to your currency converter\n Please choose your starting currency from the four options:')
currency1 = input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()

while currency1 not in ['gdp', 'eur', 'usd', 'jpy']:
    print('Sorry not accepted try again')
    currency1 = input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()
```

As the FAQ says, this "seems attractive but is generally less robust":

> The problem with this is that if you change your mind about exactly how you get the next line (e.g. you want to change it into sys.stdin.readline()) you have to remember to change two places in your program – the second occurrence is hidden at the bottom of the loop.

---

Finally, as the FAQ says, "the best approach is to use iterators, making it possible to loop through objects using the `for` statement".

That's great when you already have an iterator, or can build one trivially. But when you don't, it may add more complexity than you save. And I think that's the case here. For example, this is hardly simpler than the other options:

```
def get_currency():
    currency1=input('(GDP) = Pound Sterling £ \n(EUR) = Euro € \n(USD) = US Dollar ($) \n(JPY)= Japanese Yen ¥\n').lower()
    if currency1 in ['gdp','eur','usd','jpy']:
        return currency
    else:
        print('Sorry not accepted try again')
for currency1 in iter(get_currency, None):
    do_stuff(currency1)
```

Comment: Good answer, way better than mine. OP should accept this. I didn't think about that you have to change the code two places if you decide to change the code.

Comment: I'm missing a `do ... while` loop for these situations though. Has guido commented on this anywhere?

Comment: @SteinarLima: As far as I know, not directly, but see [PEP 315](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) and the links to the discussion threads. Briefly, he believes that `do…while` "won't make the language more elegant or easier to learn. They'd just save a few hasty folks some typing while making others who have to read/maintain their code wonder what it means." Elsewhere in the discussion, other core devs talked about its usefulness vs. misuse in C, and someone argued it's only good for the special case of `do {…} while(0)` used to force a scope (which wouldn't be relevant to Python).